# Yii cron: failed to open stream: No such file or directory (/../framework/YiiBase.php:427) while running cron

Tags: yii, cron

When i am trying to run the yii cron in server it generates the following error, but its running correctly in local environment using console,

```
2016/09/05 00:10:07 [error] [php] include(PDO.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory (/home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/YiiBase.php:427) Stack trace:
#0 unknown(0): spl_autoload_call()
#1 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(425): class_exists()
#2 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(374): CDbConnection->createPdoInstance()
#3 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#4 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive()
#5 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/base/CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#6 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/base/CModule.php(103): CConsoleApplication->getComponent()
#7 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/protected/commands/StatusChangeCommand.php(22): CConsoleApplication->__get()
#8 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): StatusChangeCommand->run()
#9 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run()
#10 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#11 /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/protected/config/cron.php(20): CConsoleApplication->run()

in /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/protected/commands/StatusChangeCommand.php (22) in /home2/GHPS/public_html/beta1/protected/config/cron.php (20)
```

I am having the following console.php,

```
<?php
```

// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.

```
return array(   'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',     'name'=>'Cron',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'ext.easy-mail.models.*',
),
// application components
'components'=>array(        

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'test',
        'password' => 'test',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

Any solution please, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Its working now, issue is because the PDO connection has not established for cron even though mysql PDO dll has enabled in server. So i have included the PDO yii extension in console.php. refer the following link,

http://www.yiilearning.com/yii-pdo-php-error-failed-open-stream-solved/